# Kik optimized card not showing in search results

Tags: kik

We have created a Kik optimized page/card called Spotzot, deals near you. Its been a few days. But when i do a search on 'Spotzot' in the top on Android, the page still doesnt show up in the 'optimized for kik'. The page url is http://spotzot.com/kikpage. Are we missing something?

Help appreciated. 
-Mihir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your canonical tag is misconfigured.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://spotzot.com">
```

The URL in the canonical tag tells search engines where the "real" version of the webpage lives so that it indexes the correct one. It looks like you're telling the search engine that your desktop version is the "real" version.

Simply change it to this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://spotzot.com/kikpage">
```

EDIT: Looks like your robots.txt is blocking KikBot (crawler for the search engine).

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Simply add this above it:

```
User-agent: KikBot
Disallow:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. We did this change. Although we are still not surfacing in the search results. We did the change 8 hours back. Does it take time to complete the crawling?

Comment: Looks like robots.txt is blocking the Kik engine. Check out my edit above